# Why are my constraints not working when rotating a modally presented child view controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

Here's my setup in iOS 8: I have a root view controller that presents modal child view controllers. I have auto layout enabled for both the parent and children VC's and carefully crafted constraints in the one storyboard. While my constrains work fine to layout my views in both parent and children, they are not repositioning views in the modal children when I rotate the device (the views are stuck in the pre-rotation sizes)!
I've chased a couple of red herrings like thinking that the rotation events were not being passed from the parent to the children, but that's not the case (the `NSLog`s in `viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator` get called in both parent and child).
Can anyone get me unstuck? Thanks!

**Update**:
I found the answer to this, but I'd like to provide more detail on the situation:
I want the Presenting View Controller to show through any transparent views in my presented View Controller, so I'm setting the modal presentation style to `UIModalPresentationCustom`

Comment: Need more detail to help with this

Comment: What kind of detail would help? I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: Think will need images showing your constraints in storyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. I finally found a solution:
- First I noticed that one of my presented view controllers was working as expected (auto-rotation would resize the views and auto-layout would do its job).
- Looking at the differences, I noticed that the only significant difference was the presentation style: the working VC was being presented with the `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` style.
- I tried changing the presentation style to full screen in my other case and, sure enough, auto layout worked as expected, only problem, the presenting view controller no longer appeared behind the transparent parts of my model VC.
- Playing with the different presentation styles I found that the style that does what I want is `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`. It's the same as full screen but shows the presenting view controller behind the presented one!

I'm still not sure why this works (couldn't find a shred of documentation describing this particular issue, if anyone does know, please share!), but what I'm baffled about is that this presentation style (`UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`) was created in iOS 8.0, meaning that I just don't know what I would have done to make this work in iOS < 8.0...

Comment: Thank you! Wished I found your answer 2 hours earlier.

Comment: Yeah this is a strange one. Has to a be an Apple bug. Because both the presenting and presented vc should be in the same orientation after rotation regardless of what style it's being presented.